# C# Unit Test : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automated-tests

So I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. The application itself runs fine and communicates with the database as it should. I simply am going back into this project to add unit tests to try to learn how to implement tests properly. I keep getting this null reference error, but I do not understand what is being thrown as null. I am hard coding the values being passed into the test. I know it has to be something simple but I have been looking at this for a couple of days now with no luck.

Error:
Message: 
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace: 
SaltWaterTankMetricRepository.Create(SaltWaterTankMetric metrics) line 25
SaltWaterTankMetricTest.CreateMetric_ShouldPass(DateTime date, Decimal temp, Decimal ph, Decimal nh3, Decimal dkh) line 42

```
    namespace SaltWaterTankMetrics.DataAccess.EF.test
{
    public class SaltWaterTankMetricTest
    {
        private readonly SaltWaterTankMetricRepository _sut;

        public SaltWaterTankMetricTest()
        {
            _sut = new SaltWaterTankMetricRepository();
        }


        [Theory]
        [InlineData("2022-11-8", 78.0, 8.3, .003, 8.2)]
        public void CreateMetric_ShouldPass(DateTime date, decimal temp, decimal ph, decimal nh3, decimal dkh)
        {
            SaltWaterTankMetric createMetrics = new SaltWaterTankMetric
            {
                MetricsDate = date,
                SaltWaterTemp = temp,
                SaltWaterPH = ph,
                SaltWaterNH3 = nh3,
                SaltWaterDKH = dkh
            };

            var result = _sut.Create(createMetrics);
            result.Should().Be(2022-11-8, "78.0", "8.3", ".003", "8.2");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Create() method in the repository file:

```
public class SaltWaterTankMetricRepository
    {
        // Database Context connection
        private SaltwaterTankContext _dbContext;

        public SaltWaterTankMetricRepository(SaltwaterTankContext context)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
        }

        public SaltWaterTankMetricRepository() { }

        public int Create(SaltWaterTankMetric metrics)
        {
            _dbContext.Add(metrics);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return metrics.MetricsID;
        }
```

And here is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SaltWaterTankMetrics.DataAccess.EF.Models
{
    public partial class SaltWaterTankMetric
    {
        public int MetricsID { get; set; }
        public DateTime MetricsDate { get; set; }
        public decimal SaltWaterTemp { get; set; }
        public decimal SaltWaterPH { get; set; }
        public decimal SaltWaterNH3 { get; set; }
        public decimal SaltWaterDKH { get; set; }

        public SaltWaterTankMetric(int metricID, DateTime date, decimal saltWaterTemp, decimal saltWaterPh, decimal saltWaterNh3, decimal saltWaterDkh)
        {
            MetricsID = metricID;
            MetricsDate = date;
            SaltWaterTemp = saltWaterTemp;
            SaltWaterPH = saltWaterPh;
            SaltWaterNH3 = saltWaterNh3;
            SaltWaterDKH = saltWaterDkh;
        }

        public SaltWaterTankMetric()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Again, this application is functioning properly when I run it. The only issues I am having are with the test itself.

Comment: The parameters of `result.Should().Be(...)` doesn't make any sense. `result` is an `int`, and `2022-11-8` isn't a valid literal (and quoting it as a string doesn't make it better). You should be able to breakpoint and debug your way though the unit test to find out what's null.

Comment: How do you initialize `_dbContext` in the `SaltWaterTankMetricRepository` class? Is that's what null?

Comment: @gunr2171 That is the only way to not throw an error from that line specifically. If it shouldn't be that then what should it show? It should be returning those parameters that I am passing in, correct? Also I cannot add in a breakpoint (at least adding one in does nothing)

Comment: @gunr2171 Added a larger view of the repository to show how _dbContext is initialized. See the original question.

Comment: You only initialize `_dbContext` when you call the constructor that accepts a parameter. In your unit test you call the constructor that _doesn't_ have a parameter, hence `_dbContext` stays null. How do you want to initialize `_dbContext` in your unit test?

Comment: You could run the test in debug mode to see where the exception originates?

Comment: Oh ok, so the null is coming from the _dbContext field in the repository. 
I thought though that passing values down into the test method would hardcode some values to pass into the constructor that I am calling. 

So with that being said, should I include _dbContext somehow in my test? I am trying to understand this as much as possible rather than someone just handing me an answer here.

Comment: @Martin I cannot run in debug mode since this is a class library. Unless there is a way to do it that I am not aware of.

Comment: Are you using the test runner of Visual Studio to execute your test? In the 'Test Explorer'  window I have two green icons on the upper left part to "Run all tests in view" and to simple to "Run". In the second icon for "Run" I have a little dropdown indicator. If you click it, a drop down menu appears with several items, among them three items to start test in Debug mode.